# How do you set up dynamic enumerables on Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a select input that takes specific User models and displays them as a string while saving them as an integer. Typically I would set the enumerable up the same way as below but as a static hash.

While attempting to create a new Product, I keep receiving the following error: "undefined local variable or method `user_business_hash'"

I've tried moving the 'user_business_hash' method to application/products controller, application/products helper with no luck.

**Model**

```
enum user_id: user_business_hash

validates :user_id, inclusion: user_ids.keys

def user_business_hash
# output: {User.business_name => User.id }
# ex: {"Business Name A"=>2, "Business Name B"=>1, "Business Name C"=>5}
array = User.where(account_type: 'Business').map{|x| [x.business_name, x.id] }

hash = array.inject({}) do |memo, (key, value)|
  memo[key] = value
  memo
end

return hash
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form.select :user_id, Product.user_ids.keys, prompt: 'Select', id: :product_user_id %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you actually want is:

on your controller

```
@options = User.where(account_type: 'Business')
```

on your view

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@options, "id", "business_name")
```